# How to loop through a d3 json treemap to get section nodes

Tags: json, d3.js, treemap

How do i loop through a treemap json object that might look like this:
and only return Section nodes as appose to node under each section node?
So, one might have a structure that looks kind of like this:

```
{
  name: "products"
  children:[
    {
      name: "Wood", 
      children: [
        { name: "rose wood" },
        { name: "maple" }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Metals", 
      children: [
        { name: "Iron" },
        { name: "copper" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
//end
```

What is want is to return only "Wood", "Metals" etc. 
Due to the redundant nature of the data, a straight forward loop does not cut it. Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do with that? I suppose you can write a recursive function to have you structure as you want it, but you can also filter the selection before drawing the nodes or branches. Take a look at the filter method of selection: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-filter

Comment: Thanks Pablo, but essentially what i am hoping to accomplish is a loop that stops and only traverses the second layer of the name attribute in the json object. It would be the equivalent of doing something like this object.name.children.name. Filter wont work for this.

Comment: I figured out my own solution and thought i might share. It was stupifyingly simple i am a bit embarrassed that i even asked. As you loop through your data within a function, d.parent.name gets the parent node for the treemap.

Comment: You can answer your own question, please explain how you did it as an answer, this way other people with the same problem would learn from your experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my code with the approach that solved my JSON parsing problem.

```
.on("mouseover",function (d) {
     $("#treemapPopup").show().html(
              "<h4>"+d.parent.name +"</h4>"+
                  "<p><strong>Good:</strong> "+d.name+"<br />"+
                  //Math.round(percent* 10)/10+"% <br />"+
                  "<strong>Countries:</strong></p>"+
                    courtryList
          );
}) ...etc
```

The d.parent.name ends up being Wood, Metals, etc as I traverse the children array of objects. And, of course, d.name is the product under Wood or Metal. Hope that helps anyone else who may have been stuck on this.

Comment: @Pablo Navarro My apologies for this being a bit late.